# Terraform not showing output despite being declared

Tags: terraform

I am declaring the following output in a TF module in the `output.tf` file:

```
output "jenkins_username" {
  value       = "${local.jenkins_username}"
  description = "Jenkins admin username"
  #sensitive   = true
}


output "jenkins_password" {
  value       = "${local.jenkins_password}"
  description = "Jenkins admin password"
  #sensitive   = true
}
```

The corresponding locals have been declared in `main.tf` as follows:

```
locals {
  jenkins_username = "${var.jenkins_username == "" ? random_string.j_username.result : var.jenkins_username}"
  jenkins_password = "${var.jenkins_password == "" ? random_string.j_password.result : var.jenkins_password}"
}
```

However, after the `apply` has finished, I see no relevant output, and what is more, it is not displayed even when I call the explicit `output` command:

```
$ terraform output jenkins_password

The output variable requested could not be found in the state
file. If you recently added this to your configuration, be
sure to run `terraform apply`, since the state won't be updated
with new output variables until that command is run.
```

Comment: Do they show in the state file if you look at the JSON directly? What address do they show as if they are listed there?

Comment: Is this your root module or are you calling this module from another one?

Comment: This is a terraform module being invoked from another one

Comment: The root module needs to pass the child module output values through its own outputs

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem. What worked for me was to comment out the output variables in the first deployment, and uncomment them once that would succeed.